# Mutating values within embedded lists in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a pandas `DataFrame` as follows:

```
 A                  B
 ...
[x1, y, z1, z2]    [1, 2, 3]
[x1, x2, z3]       [10 , 11]
...
```

It's a medium sized dataframe with `500K` rows and `50` columns. I need to mutate the dataframe such that for `col A` entries `x1, x2 ...` are replaced with `a1, a2,...` and all `z` entries are dropped.

For the example above, transformation should produce the dataframe:

```
A        B
...
[a1, y]  [1, 2, 3]
[a1, a2] [10, 11]
...
```

I could transform the dataframe to a JSON format, parse, and achieve my endstate, but that seems like a bad approach and solution.

Comment: Using pandas to manipulate lists like this doesn't make a lot of sense, In any case, I don't really follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: why? how would you do it if you have structured data in the described format?

Comment: Use some other container. For example here, just a list of lists... pandas doesn't give you many advantages when working with `dtype=object` and the items inside are non-strings. Anyway, why does the second row, for column A, change to `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Second column is not being mutated

Comment: No, to illustrate that only one column out of many is being mutated.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, it was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
df['A'] = [[i.replace('x','a') for i in x if 'z' not in i] for x in df['A']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode `A`. Use `df.replace(regex)` to replace `x` with `a`, anything starting with `z` with `NaN`. Drop the `NaN` and take back A to list.

```
   df=df.explode('A').replace(regex={r'^z.$': np.nan, 'x': 'a'}).\
dropna(thresh=2).groupby(level=0)['A'].agg(list).reset_index()
```